# Centrar input en formulario

Tags: bootstrap-4

Tengo un formulario en *Bootstrap 4.5* que tiene un input y quiero centrarlo. He intentado con
`d-flex justify-content-center` y también con `text-center`.
En qué me estoy equivocando?

```
<div class="row col-md-12">
    <form action="archivo.php" name="salir" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Salir" value="Salir">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: En qué parte de  las etiquetas estás añadiendo las clases?

Comment: Usando las clases que has dicho a mi se me ha centrado: https://jsfiddle.net/n4kobvr3/

Comment: Sí centra al separar `<div class="row col-md-12">` en dos __divs__ como pusiste en tu código. No sabía que había que separarlo de esa manera.

Comment: Sin separarlo tambien me funcionaba, pero la forma correcta es usar los dos divs por separado porque ambas clases generan unos paddings o margins distintos y su unión puede dar como resultado algo imprevisto si luego usas mas rows en otros elementos a continuación de este.

Comment: Bueno lo solucioné con los `divs` separados.

Answer (score 1):

podrías intentar de ésta manera, aplicando el centrado al row

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row col-md-12" style="justify-content: center;">
        <form action="archivo.php" name="salir" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Salir" value="Salir">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```